# How do I prevent keypress eventListner from setting my state variable to true then false?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
    const [shout, setShout] = useState(true);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("hello world!");

    window.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
        console.log(shout);
        if(e.key === "a" && shout === true) {
            setMessage(message.toUpperCase())
        }
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{message}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => setShout(!shout)}>disable keypress!</button>
            <button onClick={() => setMessage(message.toLowerCase())}>to lower case</button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default App;
```

When I press the `a` button on my keyboard the message is transformed to uppercase if the disable `keypress` button is not clicked. If it's clicked pressing `a` key should not upper case the message.
When I `console.log` the shout variable in the `eventListner` callback it seems like the shout variable is set from true to false simultaneously.
How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to add side effects in react and also to make sure your listener is removed once the component un-mounts.

Also I prefer `document` instead of `window` but I don't think that makes a difference.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
    const [shout, setShout] = useState(true);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("hello world!");

    useEffect(() => {
        const listener = (e) => {
            if(e.key === "a" && shout === true) {
                console.log(e.key, shout);
                setMessage(message.toUpperCase());
            }
        };

        document.addEventListener("keypress", listener);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keypress', listener);
        };
    }, [shout, message]);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{message}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => setShout(!shout)}>disable keypress!</button>
            <button onClick={() => setMessage(message.toLowerCase())}>to lower case</button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Feel free to mark this as the answer then. It'll give me them imaginary internet points we are all here for ;)